# Using an object as a method's argument in es 6

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to take a new `Point` object as the argument of the `plus` method and then add to return the value. `Point p` will be correct in java but not in javascript.

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    plus(Point p) {
        console.log(p.a);
        return new Point(p.a + this.x, p.b + this.y);
    }
}

console.log(new Point(1, 2).plus(new Point(2, 1)));

// → Point{x: 3, y: 3}
```

Comment: `Point p` isn't valid JS, are you using a type hinter, or compiled language like typescript?

Comment: Arguments in JavaScript are not typed; just write `plus(p) { ... }`

Comment: Isn't it just a typo? `p.x + this.x, p.y + this.y`

Comment: Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet. Forget anything you know about Java when writing Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the right properties and arguments without type.

```js
class Point {

    constructor (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    plus (p) {
        return new Point(p.x + this.x, p.y + this.y);
    }
}

console.log(new Point(1, 2).plus(new Point(2, 1)));
```